# How to tune upload of data from (non EMR) Hive to S3?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive

I want to copy data from a hive table on a bare-metal hadoop cluster to an Amazon S3 bucket.

I understand that I can do something like this:

```
hive> create external table my_table
> (
> `column1` string,
> `column2` string,
  ....
> `columnX` string)
> row format delimited fields terminated by ','
> lines terminated by '\n'
> stored as textfile
> location 's3n://my_bucket/my_folder_path/';

hive> insert into table my_table select * from source_db.source_table;
```

And it works for small sets of data. But if I try it with a larger set of data, I get errors with stack traces like the one below.

I'm looking for some help on ways that I can tune this process or other options.

Thanks in advance.

```
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:172)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1709)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.VectorMapOperator.process(VectorMapOperator.java:52)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:163)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.createBucketFiles(FileSinkOperator.java:577)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.process(FileSinkOperator.java:675)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.VectorFileSinkOperator.process(VectorFileSinkOperator.java:102)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:838)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.VectorSelectOperator.process(VectorSelectOperator.java:138)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:838)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.process(TableScanOperator.java:117)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.forward(MapOperator.java:167)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.VectorMapOperator.process(VectorMapOperator.java:45)
        ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Hive is clearly telling you the problem. Look at these two lines:

- Hive Runtime Error while processing row
- IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive
  So, it's not a problem of small dataset vs large. Rather, your large dataset has some rows, which Hive isn't able to process.

However, it is difficult to pinpoint the exact problem with what information you've posted. I'd suggest that you break down your large dataset into smaller chunks, and try to narrow down the issue.

Comment: "Hive is clearly telling you the problem..."
"it is difficult to pinpoint the exact problem..."

Right. So it actually isn't that clear. 
And that's the full stack trace.
The data is ALREADY in Hive. I'm just asking Hive to copy the bits to S3. 

That said, I will experiment with data content vs data size.

Comment: "The data is ALREADY in Hive" - just because you created a table on a dataset, doesn't mean Hive has actually loaded the data, right?

Comment: during create-table, all it does is store information for that data in its metastore. it doesn't actually read the data